# New Named Set in SSAS used in Pivot Table - MDX

Tags: ssas, parent-child, mdx, pivot-table, olap

I created a `New Named Set` called `DB III o. PE`  defined as `DB III`, `Umlage HL`, `Umlage NV`, `Umlage UL` . 
When I use this new Set in a Pivot Tabel or in MDX I see the content of this Set and not his given name `DB III o. PE`.
Is there a possibility to see the given name instead of his content?

Example attached:[image]

The set is created like this:

[image]

**UPDATE:**
I created also a measure called [Amount Standard Set] because before Set I needed first to multiply with -1 the Amount of `Umlage HL`, `Umlage NV`, `Umlage UL` .

The measure is defined as:

```
case 
    when [Kostenart Hierarchy].[Kostenart Hierarchy].currentmember= [Kostenart Hierarchy].[Kostenart Hierarchy].&[148]
        then -1* [Measures].Amount
    when [Kostenart Hierarchy].[Kostenart Hierarchy].currentmember= [Kostenart Hierarchy].[Kostenart Hierarchy].&[147]
        then -1* [Measures].Amount
    when [Kostenart Hierarchy].[Kostenart Hierarchy].currentmember= [Kostenart Hierarchy].[Kostenart Hierarchy].&[150]
        then -1* [Measures].Amount


    else Amount
end
```

Comment: is this new measure defined in your cube script? In other words - if you're not using xl-2013 where have you written this measure?

Comment: @whytheq  I created a calculated member directly in the Cube, in SSAS

Comment: ok - well I'd definitely not use the operator `=` rather change it to `IS`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is behaving as it should. A set is several distinct members.

You require a custom member that is the amalgamation of your set.

Create a custom member called `DB III o. PE Agg` and define it as something like the following `mdx`:

```
`Aggregate([DB III o. PE])`
```

This is using the `Aggregate` function:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms145524.aspx

Create this custom member in the dimension where the elements of the set {DB III, Umlage HL, Umlage NV, Umlage UL} are found.

If you are using Excel 2013 you should have a option in the OLAP Tools menu "MDX Calculated Member.."

Comment: thank you very much. It worked. I tested in MDX and I implemented already in SSAS.

Comment: For the members of the set: Umlage HL, Umlage NV, Umlage UL I need first to multiply the value by -1 and then to aggregate the set. Is there a way to handle this in the custom member created  ?

Comment: @PirvuGeorgian that is more of a custom measure. Which xl are you using? In the recent versions there is an option to add a custom measure.

Comment: I am using Excel 2010... I think this option is available with Excel 2013

Comment: I created a new measure based on a case when statement where I multiply the Amount with -1 only for those members and i used this new measure in the pivot table only with the Set. I think this was also your idea...

Comment: @PirvuGeorgian - please add your new measure to the original question: you need some care when using CASE - it can cause efficiency issues

Comment: ...I updated the original question with the new informations